# Cannot find module `libsodium-wrappers`

Tags: typescript, libsodium

I'm running some of my tests and receive error `Cannot find module libsodium-wrappers from src/crypto/hash.ts`

This is how I import this package
`import libsodium from 'libsodium-wrappers';`

I've installed this package via `yarn add @types/libsodium-wrappers`

Seems like node cannot find such package, but it presents in node_modules directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try also `yarn add libsodium-wrappers`

Answer (score 2):

Prefix `@types` usually means that this package contains only type definitions. There is no business logic behind.

It means that you also need to install `libsodium-wrappers` with `yarn add libsodium-wrappers`.

Please see [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) and [related section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) in TS docs